# SVG not working after exporting from Bootstrap Studio

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, svg

I'm trying to export my Bootstrap Studio project. In preview mode, the SVG is working fine and `<use>` is working, but after exporting `<use>` isn't working anymore and Bootstrap cannot setup file path for the SVG file.

How can I fix the problem?

```
<svg class="svg icon" aria-hidden="true">
    <use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="standard-sprite.svg#contact"></use>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

well your path is broken as you write.

```
xlink:href="standard-sprite.svg#contact"
```

change this according to the export location.

maybe  the file is in a folder on your desktop, server or an image folder.
so it should be somthing like

```
xlink:href="images/svg/standard-sprite.svg#contact"
```

or is the svg inlined in your html?

the you would do sort of like this
put your sprite svg in the html in a hidden div

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" style="display: none">
  <symbol id="standard-sprite" viewBox="0 0 20 20">
    <title>standard-sprite</title>
    <path d="..." />
  </symbol>
</svg>
```

and later in the html call your svg

```
<svg>
  <use xlink:href="#standard-sprite" />
</svg>
```